# How to unload iframe until It is displayed

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have deployed many iframes to show and hide for each tab,

```
<div class="slide" data-slide="1">
       <iframe src="url" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="slide" data-slide="2">
       <iframe src="url" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="slide" data-slide="3">
       <iframe src="url" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

this is how its code look likes. although some buttons is not displayed.
there is the buttons matching for each iframe.
every time each buttons is clicked, then, matching iframe will be shown to user.

let's imagine that we have 100 iframes.

browser will load so many iframes. then, the users have to spend a lot of times.

so definetely I want to unload iframes until It is displyed.

how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically change the "src" attribute of the iframe on button click event.

Something like:

```
<button data-url="http://google.com">Google</button>
<button data-url="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo!</button>
<button data-url="http://aol.com">Aol.</button>
<iframe id="myFrame" src="http://google.com" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

Using jQuery:

```
$( "button" ).on( "click", function(){
     var _url = $( this ).data( "url" );
     $( "#myFrame" ).attr( "src", _url );
})
```

Doing so, you will just need a single frame element opposed to frames equivalent to no of buttons.